# Compare Two DataTable?

Tags: vb.net

i want to compare the two data table columns and find duplicates

for example

dataTable1 
 autoid  ponbr polinenbr quantity  
 1      0001   10          5      
 2      0002   12          6      
 3      0003   15          7

dataTable2 
 autoid ponbr polinenbr quantity 
 1       0001   10          5 
 2       0002   15          7 
 3       0003   12          9

in the above two dataTable i would like to compare the ponbr and polinenbr column and find the duplicates and get the autoid..

how to do it in vb.net

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 Loops

```
Foreach (DataRow row1 In dataTable1)
{
   Foreach (DataRow row2 In dataTable2)
   {
       if (row1[1] == [row2[1])
       {
         // means ponbr matched
         // do your stuff
         return row2[0];   //returns the autoid from datatable2 
       }
       if (row1[2] == [row2[2])
       {
         // means polinenbr matched
         // do your stuff
         return row2[0];  //returns the autoid from datatable2
       }

   } 
}
```

im sorry if this is in C# i dont have VB installed in my VS and i cant write them without IDE because i was focusing on my C# and forgot my VB skills.

But i hope this would still be useful for you

Answer (score 0):

Can you check these answers ?

here you can join the table with another, similar the way SQL join works\
Just have a try on this.

[How To: Use DataRelation to perform a join on two DataTables in a DataSet?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/331265/how-to-use-datarelation-to-perform-a-join-on-two-datatables-in-a-dataset)

[Inner join of DataTables in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp)